# android.gms.common.SignInButton in MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Hey I want to implement a leaderboard hosted in the new google play developer console into my game. In the tutorial, you have to extend your Activity class with `BaseGameActivity`. Because you can't extend 2 different classes, I thought it would make sense to make another class where the `extends BaseGameActivity` finds its place so I can call the `BaseGameActivity` everytime I need them from my MainActivity (which extends Activity e.g. for UI elements).

I call the sign in function in my MainActivity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {       
        if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
              new Submit().signin();
        }
```

Submit is the class that extends BaseGameActivity, the method `signin()` looks like that:

```
public  void signin()
{ beginUserInitiatedSignIn();}
```

If I do it like that, clicking google's sign in button, I get following error (app forces close):

```
07-02 02:34:35.491: E/AndroidRuntime(21287): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 02:34:35.491: E/AndroidRuntime(21287):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:131)
07-02 02:48:51.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 02:48:51.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21431): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 02:48:51.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21431):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:116)
07-02 02:48:51.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21431):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
07-02 02:48:51.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21431):    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn(GameHelper.java:445)
07-02 02:48:51.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21431):    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity.beginUserInitiatedSignIn(BaseGameActivity.java:132)
07-02 02:48:51.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21431):    at PACKAGENAME.Submit.signin(Submit.java:25)
07-02 02:48:51.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21431):    at PACKAGENAME.APPNAME.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:181)
```

When I try to mess  around with getting contexts or anything like that, pretty similar errors show up.

Is my idea to manage the google methods in another class wrong or is it even undoable like that? If not, how should I manage the UI elements when I am not extending Activity because I want to extend `BaseGameActivity` ?

Sorry if my text looks messy but I am sitting at this problem now for 6 hours and my eyes are bleeding right now..

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

Firstly I got the sample app (TypeANumber) working.

Then I loosely integrated the Google code into my app (I simply started an activity something like TypeANumber when the user clicks on a button which then used BaseGameUtils in the normal way). This is, I think, what you plan to do and the way Google now seem to be recommending that you do things (see 
https://developers.google.com/live/shows/5936979195723776).

However, you have probably seen that BaseGameUtils comprises two classes - BaseGameActivity and GameHelper. BaseGameActivity is a relatively simple piece of code and GameHelper does most of the real work. In the absence of guidance to the contrary at the time, I simply  wrote my own version of BaseGameActivity to fit into my existing app structure (action bar tabs/ fragments) copied GameHelper into my project and managed to get it working without too much difficulty. Of course, one advantage of this approach was that I did not need to extend BaseGame...

I hope this helps. I have seen the particular NPE error that you have encountered before - please check that you have installed Google Play Game services on the device / emulator that you are running on (if you are using the emulator - the Google APIs are required).

Comment: Ok I now figured out that BaseGameActivity includes all Activity functions. Somehow my PC and me didn't figure out this in first instance. Thanks for your hint, I'll mark it as answer :) Greets

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a similar issue.
The solution for me was to avoid calling from a different thread.
It would appear that some methods in the BaseGameActivity class are not thread safe.

I was getting the correct behaviour only on about 1 of 4 attempts until I used this code:

```
public void signin(){
    //Run this code on the main thread.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {      
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Check if user is signed in
            if (!MainActivity.this.isSignedIn()){
                try{
                    //if not, attempt to sign in
                    beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    //Handle errors with an alert box
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 
                    alert.setTitle("Unable to sign in");
                    alert.setMessage("The app was unable to sign in to G+. An error occured.");
                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                    alert.show();
                }
            }       
        }
    });
}
```

instead of this code:

```
public void signin(){
    beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
}
```

This is probably only the solution if you are using other threads. If you do not use any threads other than the main thread then this is not the solution.

Most games will use more than one thread and so this is likely to be a problem other people run in to.

--edit--

After trying that for a while, I find the same problem again.
There is a pattern however. If the phone orientation changes, the app cannot log in properly.
It would appear I have actually done something very wrong in my app.
The thing that caused this for me was having an old pointer to the main activity instance. The game client had another instance pointer that didn't match up.